# Transition time (rise time) and propagation delay

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, delay, propagation

Recently in class I have encountered the following calculation of the propagation delay of the following digital circuit:
[image]
[image]

Could anyone please explain to me the addition of the rising time of X2 and C? I fail to understand why this addition is regarded as the "real" propagation delay.

Comment: Did the question mention what family of devices are being used, CMOS, TTL, ECL, etc..?  I am trying to make sense of where the divide by 2 comes from.

Comment: I believe cmos...

Comment: I am surmising that by tr(C) they actually mean tr(Y0). The threshold voltage for CMOS logic levels is around 1/2 the supply voltage, so maybe they are emphasizing that the rise time of the input signal to reach the 0-->1 (0.5 supply voltage) threshold is non-zero and likewise with the output signal effect on the target destination. I am unsure. These delays are generally small compared to other delays.

Comment: I am voting to close this, as without timing diagrams, or definitions of how times are measured/calculated, a conclusive answer cannot be given.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the way propagation delay (say \$t_{pLH}\$) is defined. See the figure:

[image]

Conventional, it is measured between the mid-points of the transition.

Now if you define *real propagation delay* (\$t_{p,real}\$) as the time duration between the point at which input started rising and the point at which the the output settles to final value, then one can write:

real propagation delay = time required for input to rise to 50% + propagation delay + time required for output to reach final value from 50% point. 
$$t_{p,real} = t_{pLH}+t_{in,0\to 50\%}+t_{out,50\to 100\%}$$

So that's why half of rise times are added with the conventional propagation delay to calculate the *real propagation delay*.